# I want to use any other function of R instead of sprintf for calculating groups of list

Tags: r

I have sequences of a gene consisting of different species and they are grouped together (on the basis of similarities)in the form of list  and I have to calculate that how many groups are identified for each gene. It has been done with sprintf function and I want to do this with anyother function of R. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
sprintf("%s series form %.0f group(s).", list11, length(unique(unlist(list11[[1]][1]))))
```

Comment: Why exactly you don't want to use `sprintf` ?

Comment: just wondering for some alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste`/`paste0` :

```
paste(list11, 'series form',  length(unique(unlist(list11[[1]][1]))), 'group(s)')
```